# Is the Google AdSense pluging for Wordpress all I need to use to activate AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

First time setting up AdSense so please bear with me if the question is silly. I have created an AdSense account and installed the Google AdSense plugin for Wordpress, I have configured it and I have selected the ad placement on the pages of my site (I see all the ad units in my AdSense dashboard as well).

Now, if I go back to my AdSense homepage, I see this:

[image]

I am a bit confused here: is the Wordpress plugin all I need to activate AdSense or do I have to manually place the code on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: the Wordpress plugin is all that you need, as I received confirmation from Google that my account had been successfully setup.

I guess the AdSense homepage was just a bit confusing as I was expecting a little green checkmark to appear next to "Place the adcode on the website" but that just isn't the case apparently.